# What's this BGA chip and what's its purpose?

Tags: chipset

I opened a computer of one of my friends to see if something was wrong inside it. I'm not an hardware expert at all, in fact when I looked inside it, I thought one component was the CPU, because of its squared shape similar to a CPU, but apparently it isn't the CPU, since the CPU is usually under the cooler. (Note the cooler is below the graphics cards in red that you see in the picture below, i.e. the cooler is not visible in the picture)

This is a picture of the squared chip (I included other parts so that you can have a more natural feeling of its position and the relation with the other components):

[image]

I looked online for the name "SLJ48" (which is written on the chip in very tiny font) and something came out, for example:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/1x-Used-Intel-BDB2H61-5LJ4B-BD82H6I-SLJ48-BD82H61SLJ4B-BD82H61-SLJ4B-BGA-Chip-/190857334218

but no clear explanation...

So, if that isn't the CPU, what the heck is that and what's the purpose of that chip?

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/52806/Intel-BD82H61-PCH It is the all in one chipset for stuff like PCI, USB, SATA, etc. As far as the soldered part, this package is a BGA (Ball Grid Array) and is intended for OEM use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by the eBay page, it's the [H61 Chipset Platform Controller Hub](http://ark.intel.com/products/52806/Intel-BD82H61-PCH). It contains the SATA and USB controllers and provides additional PCIe lanes, among other things.

Comment: SouthBridge is another common term for this technology. It connects all the integrated pepripherals like disks. I would mention that video card PCIe connections are supposed to be connected to the Northbridge, which nowadays is mostly integrated into the CPU itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Motherboard_diagram.svg

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a part of the chipset -- a north- or a south-bridge. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)) Wikipedia article explains it well.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted your answer. That chip is the southbridge. In the answer above, the H61 Chipset Platform Controller Hub is just a specific chip name for the southbridge. You see by the [picture](https://imgur.com/lxsDovP) it's obviously the southbridge.